# how to check if user input is a certain character

Tags: c, if-statement

I am trying to check if the user inputs y or something else.

I have tried creating a string and looping through what the user inputs, but that doesn't work.

```
char answer[] = "n";
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(answer)/4; i++) {
    if(answer[i] == "y") {
       calculatorPrompt();
    } else if(answer[i] === "n") {
              printf("Okay, bye!");
              System(100);
    }
}
```

This is my code (I'm sure it crashes on the if statement):

```
printf("Thanks for that\nDo you want a calculator?(y/n)");
char answer = 'n';
scanf("%s", answer);
    if(answer == 'y') {
        calculatorPrompt();
    } else if(answer == 'n') {
        printf("Okay bye!");
        Sleep(100); //wait for 100 milliseconds
    }
```

`calculatorPrompt()` function:

```
void calculatorPrompt() {
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
int sum = 0;
printf("Enter your first number: ");
if(scanf("%d\n", a) != 1) {
    checkNumber();
} else {
    printf("Enter your second number: ");
    if(scanf("%d\n", b) != 1) {
        checkNumber();
    } else {
        sum = calculate(a, b);
        printf("Your answer is: %d", sum);
    }
}

}
```

`calculate()` function:

```
int calculate(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

`checkNumber()` function:

```
void checkNumber() {
    printf("Really? You didn't enter a number... Now exiting..");
    return;
}
```

I have included `<windows.h> <stdio.h>` and `<stdbool.h>`

I'm also confused as to why it crashes.

The return value of the program is -1,073,741,819.

Comment: Please provide more detail. It crashes isn't a very good description.

Comment: For one,  crashes because you didn't research how [**`scanf()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) works. Hint: `scanf("%s", answer)`, where `answer` is simply `char`, isn't right. In fact, *none* of the usages of `scanf` in the posted code are correct, so I'd advise some time learning about it before using it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll research more into scanf.

Comment: why did you use `i < sizeof(answer)/4`  in the `for` loop?

Comment: Well I originally used it to find the number of elements in the string, but now I realized that a string doesn't have 4 bytes...

Comment: No! it must be `i < sizeof(answer)`, as in a string every element occupies only `1` byte not `4` (you are mistaking it for an `int array`)

Comment: Yea, I just realized that. But I don't understand what @WhozCraig is saying about how every one of my `scanf()` function calls are incorrect in my code.

Comment: After reviewing my code, it seems like I just made a lot of careless mistakes, mistakes I could've easily avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You have multiple issues with `scanf()` statements in the code :

- in `calculatorPrompt()` funtion of your code, you use :

  ```
  if(scanf("%d\n", a) != 1) //wrong : sending variable as argument
  ```
- This is wrong because you need to send `address of the variable` as the argument not the `variable` itself as argument.

  ```
  if(scanf("%d", &a) != 1) //correct : sending address as argument
  ```
- similarly change while scanning other `integers` in the code.

---

here,

```
char answer = 'n';
scanf("%s", answer);
```

- As you are using the wrong *format specifier*, this invokes **Undefined behavior**.
- here since `answer` is a `char` so, instead use :

  ```
  scanf(" %c", &answer); //space to avoid white spaces
  ```

---

and as I've already suggested in the comments :

- You use `i < sizeof(answer)/4` in the `for` loop

> No! it must be `i < sizeof(answer)`, as in a string every element occupies only `1` byte not `4` *(you are mistaking it for an* `int` *array)*

*by the way you don't have any **strings** in your code*

Comment: ^ :)  & it might be worth mentioning why `scanf("%s", answer);` is disastrous

Comment: Sorry overlooked it for `printf`. But if the op uses `printf("%s", answer);` for printing they would get a seg fault.

Comment: Yes it is undefined behavior and it it NOT always a segfault.

Comment: yup thanks for taking time @sjsam really appreciate your help :D i'll include that in my answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend the code you have written for calculator, yet wanted to help you find the working code. Try following code that is based on your own code. Hope you'll see the differences and understand the reasons why the program was crashing in your case.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
bool checkNumber(int num)
{
    return true;
}


int calculate(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

void calculatorPrompt() {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    printf("Enter your first number: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &a);
    if (checkNumber(a)) {
    }

    printf("Enter your second number: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &b);
    if (checkNumber(b)) {
    }

    sum = calculate(a, b);
    printf("Your answer is: %d", sum);

}

int main()
{
    printf("Thanks for that\nDo you want a calculator?(y/n)");
    char answer = 'n';
    scanf_s("%c", &answer);
    if (answer == 'y') {
        calculatorPrompt();
    }
    else if (answer == 'n') {
        printf("Okay bye!");
        Sleep(100); //wait for 100 milliseconds
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain the changes you've made

Comment: 1. modified scanf to take address of variable as argument 2. there was if else block based on return value of scanf. That code block looked not correct. Ideally one should do number validation and handle any unexpected values. So moved checknumber call out of if block. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

void calculatorPrompt(void);

int main(void){
    printf("Thanks for that\nDo you want a calculator?(y/n)");
    char answer = 'n';
    scanf("%c", &answer);//scanf need address of store place
    if(answer == 'y') {
        calculatorPrompt();
    } else if(answer == 'n') {
        printf("Okay bye!\n");
        Sleep(100); //wait for 100 milliseconds
    }
    return 0;
}

void checkNumber(void);
int calculate(int a, int b);

void calculatorPrompt() {
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    printf("Enter your first number: ");
    if(scanf("%d", &a) != 1) {//\n : skip white spaces and wait input not spaces
        checkNumber();//call when invalid input
    } else {
        printf("Enter your second number: ");
        if(scanf("%d", &b) != 1) {
            checkNumber();
        } else {
            sum = calculate(a, b);
            printf("Your answer is: %d\n", sum);
        }
    }
}

void checkNumber(void){//output message and clear input.
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid input!\n");
    scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");//clear upto end of line.
}

int calculate(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you scan a character , you just need to use %c. If you are planning to continue with string you must use strcmp() for comparison not ==.